# how to properly remove banned words?

Tags: haskell

I have a line from which I want to remove all words beginning with the symbol `@`, I do not fully understand how to do it expressively. It is clear that you could write something like this:

1. Split the string into words
2. Use the list filter to weed out unnecessary words

But I guess I don't understand how to break lines, because in addition to the space, there are such characters as `\t` and `\n`, besides, I will lose them and can not restore the original text.

An example of what I want to get:

original string:

```
haha lala\n@delete_me all-ok
```

expected result:

```
haha lala\nall-ok
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [`Data.List.Split.split`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.5/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:split) with [`Data.List.Split.oneOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.5/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:oneOf).

It returns split words including separators, so you can rebuild text with them.

```
split (oneOf "xyz") "aazbxyzcxd" == ["aa","z","b","x","","y","","z","c","x","d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at the problem is that we want to delete strings of non-spaces that begin with an at sign `@`, as well as any following spaces. We don’t want to treat line breaks or other characters specially at all. That can be expressed with a simple recursive function using `span` / `break` and `dropWhile`:

```
censor :: String -> String

censor "" = ""

censor text0 = spaces ++ nonspaces ++ censor rest
  where

    (spaces, text1) = span isSpace text0

    (word, text2) = break isSpace text1

    (nonspaces, rest)

      | banned word
      = ("", trim text2)

      | otherwise
      = (word, text2)

banned :: String -> Bool
banned ('@' : _) = True
banned _ = False

trim :: String -> String
trim = dropWhile isSpace
```

Consider an example:

1. `censor "  send @beans money to sam@example.com"`
2. `span` returns `"  "` and `"send @beans…"`
3. `break` returns `"send"` and `" @beans…"`
4. `banned` returns false for `"send"`, so we will keep it
5. We recursively call `censor " @beans money…"`
6. `span` returns `" "` and `"@beans money…"`
7. `break` returns `"@beans"` and `" money…"`
8. Now `banned` returns true for `"@beans"`, so we drop it and trim the rest
9. We recursively call `censor "money…"`
10. We keep all the remaining substrings, including `sam@example.com`, since it is not `banned`
11. Finally, we reach the end of the string and `censor ""` returns `""`

The end result is this expression:

```
"  " ++ "send" ++ " " ++ "" ++ "money" ++ " " ++ "to" ++ " " ++ "sam@example.com" ++ ""
```

Notice that we use a series of updates to the input string resulting in a series of variables `text0`, `text1`, `text2`, `rest` for the intermediate states. Consider how you could express this pattern using `State` instead.